# Query for updatate a table with incremental values in Netezza

Tags: sql-update, netezza

I have a table in prod which is having huge data, recently I have added new column for that table and loaded surrogate values for new rows. Existing rows are null's.
Now I want to update this new columns with max value+1 incremental values where new columns are null. Can any one please provide solution for this scenario.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How big is "huge?"  How many GB/TB on what model Netezza system?  How did you generate the surrogate key values for the new rows?

Comment: Its around 8 million records, and I had prepared below query,

Comment: UPDATE IM_CS_SESSION_FIRST_PAGE_FACT_temp Target
    SET Target.SESSION_FIRST_PAGE_KEY = R.rowNum
    FROM IM_CS_SESSION_FIRST_PAGE_FACT T
    JOIN (
(SELECT T2.SESSION_ID,
              (select Max(SESSION_FIRST_PAGE_KEY) from IM_CS_SESSION_FIRST_PAGE_FACT)+(
              row_number() over (order by T2.SESSION_FIRST_PAGE_KEY desc)) as rowNum
              from IM_CS_SESSION_FIRST_PAGE_FACT T2 Group by T2.Session_Id,T2.SESSION_FIRST_PAGE_KEY)
              ) R on T.SESSION_ID=R.SESSION_ID 
       Where  T.SESSION_FIRST_PAGE_KEY Is Null or T.SESSION_FIRST_PAGE_KEY=0